# Sorbet Interface requires implementation signature types to be equal to or an ancestor of the type instead of a descendant

Tags: ruby, generics, interface, sorbet

The following sample code results in a `srb` error with note: A parameter's type must be a supertype of the same parameter's type on the super method.

```
editor.rb:29: Block parameter _block of type T.proc.params(arg0: T.class_of(Admin::PostAuthAction::PostActionContext)).returns(Admin::PostAuthAction::PostActionContext) not compatible with type of abstract method Lifecycle::PostAuthAction#sync https://srb.help/5035
    29 |    def sync(&_block)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    editor.rb:11: The super method parameter _block was declared here with type T.proc.params(arg0: T.class_of(T::Struct)).returns(T::Struct)
    11 |    def sync(&_block); end
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Note:
    A parameter's type must be a supertype of the same parameter's type on the super method.
```

```rb
# typed: strict

module Lifecycle
  module PostAuthAction
    extend T::Sig
    extend T::Helpers

    interface!

    sig do
      abstract.params(
        _block: T.proc.params(arg0: T.class_of(T::Struct)).returns(T::Struct)
      ).void
    end
    def sync(&_block); end
  end
end

module Admin
  class PostAuthAction
    include Lifecycle::PostAuthAction
    extend T::Sig

    class PostActionContext < T::Struct
      const :user, Object
    end

    PostActionContextCallback = T.type_alias do
      T.proc.params(arg0: T.class_of(PostActionContext)).returns(PostActionContext)
    end

  
    sig { override.params(_block: PostActionContextCallback).void }
    def sync(&_block)
      context = yield(PostActionContext)
    end
  end
end
```

My expectation is that the interface should define the upper bound wherein the signature of the interface expects a block which accepts a Class `T::Struct` and returns an instance of `T::Struct`.

The implementation provides a subclass of `T::Struct` and results in this typing error. The interface instead defines the lower bound of the inheritance and I can only provide Ancestors of `T::Struct` instead of descendants.

What gives?

I am able to accomplish the expected LSP (Liskov substitution) if I add generics. Here is [a plaground](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Amodule%20Lifecycle%0A%20%20module%20PostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface!%0A%0A%20%20%20%20sig%20%7B%20abstract.params%28_block%3A%20T.proc.params%28arg0%3A%20T.class_of%28T%3A%3AStruct%29%29.returns%28T%3A%3AStruct%29%29.void%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20def%20sync%28%26_block%29%3B%20end%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0A%0Amodule%20Admin%0A%20%20class%20PostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20include%20Lifecycle%3A%3APostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20PostActionContext%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%3Auser%2C%20Object%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20%20%20PostActionContextCallback%20%3D%20T.type_alias%20%7B%20T.proc.params%28arg0%3A%20T.class_of%28PostActionContext%29%29.returns%28PostActionContext%29%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20sig%20%7B%20override.params%28_block%3A%20PostActionContextCallback%29.void%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20def%20sync%28%26_block%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20context%20%3D%20yield%28PostActionContext%29%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20end%0Aend)  for the code above, and a [solution using generics](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20strict%0A%0Amodule%20Lifecycle%0A%20%20module%20PostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%0A%20%20%20%20U%20%3D%20type_member%0A%0A%20%20%20%20interface!%0A%0A%20%20%20%20sig%20%7B%20abstract.params%28_block%3A%20T.proc.params%28arg0%3A%20T%3A%3AClass%5BU%5D%29.returns%28U%29%29.void%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20def%20sync%28%26_block%29%3B%20end%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Amodule%20Admin%0A%20%20class%20PostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20include%20Lifecycle%3A%3APostAuthAction%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20%20%20class%20PostActionContext%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%3Auser%2C%20Object%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20PostActionContextCallback%20%3D%20T.type_alias%20%7B%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20U%20%3D%20type_member%20%7B%7B%20fixed%3A%20PostActionContext%20%7D%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20sig%20%7B%20override.params%28_block%3A%20T.proc.params%28arg0%3A%20T.class_of%28PostActionContext%29%29.returns%28PostActionContext%29%29.void%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20def%20sync%28%26_block%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20context%20%3D%20yield%28PostActionContext%29%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20end%0Aend)

Comment: Sorbet is correct here, the block in `PostAuthAction` could have been called with _any_ `T::Struct`. Your subclass constrains that by only supporting being called with a `PostActionContext` (or subtype of it), which is an LSP-breaking override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorbet is right in complaining about the original implementation: the child class can't override a method to receive a more specific type than the parent.

To see why this is a problem, look at the following example:

```rb
class Food; end
class Grass < Food; end
class Meat < Food; end

module Animal
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers

  interface!

  sig do
    abstract.params(food: Food).void
  end
  def eat(food); end
  end
end

class Elephant
  include Animal

  # Sorbet doesn't allow this, which shows that my modeling is wrong:
  # I can't make `Animal` eat `Food` if then I want some animals to
  # be herbivores!
  sig do
    override.params(food: Grass).void
  end
  def eat(food); end
end

# Now, let's suppose that I ignore the type-checking Sorbet does:

sig {params(animal: Animal, food: Food}
def feed(animal, food)
  animal.eat(food) # Here, I could be giving meat to a non-meat-eater!
end

feed(Elephant.new, Meat.new)
```

The key is to follow the [Robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): "be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept". When dealing with Sorbet signatures, this means:

- You can declare the `params` to be of the type, or more general (parent) than what's in the parent's signature.
- You can declare the `returns` *only* to be of the type, or a more specific (child) than what's in the parent's signature.

Comment: I get it! For some reason I was trapped thinking I had to set my signature to match the exact return types. In the end I was going to return a subtype of the interface anyways so its fine. Thanks for the example!

Comment: I'm adding this to my response, but the trick is to follow the [Robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): "be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept"